# Property default values based on another property's value

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

In Realm,

Is it possible to set the default value of a persisted property, based on the value of another property?

For example. I have a `name` property that includes UpperCase/LowerCase/Accents/etc. I want to have a `tokenizedName` that transforms the `name` property into a more simple string (all undercase, no accents).

Comment: `tokenizedName` could be a readonly property with a getter that creates result on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do this with derived properties:

```
class Person: Object {
  var name: String {
    get {
      return _name
    }
    set {
      _name = newValue
      // perform tokenization...
      tokenizedName = _name.lowercaseString
    }
  }
  private dynamic var _name = ""
  dynamic var tokenizedName = ""

  override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] { return ["name"] }
}
```

Here `_name` and `tokenizedName` are properties persisted in Realm, while `name` is ignored. Every time you read from `name`, you're just from its underlying storage. Every time you write to `name`, you set its backing storage and update the tokenized version.

---

**Edit: In Objective-C**

```
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property NSString *_name;
@property NSString *tokenizedName;
@end

@implementation Person
- (NSString *)name {
  return self._name;
}
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
  self._name = name;
  // perform tokenization...
  self.tokenizedName = name.lowercaseString;
}
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)ignoredProperties {
  return @[@"name"];
}
@end
```

Comment: i don't think this falls under the `objective-c` tag ;) but the idea is sound

Comment: Oh, sorry I hadn't seen the tag and the question body didn't specify, but yes, this should be trivially convertible to Objective-C syntax.